# Running Flink Program on a Remote Cluster

Tags: apache-flink

I have a program in Apache Flink. I tested and ran it on the local machine and every thing works fine. To run the program on a remote cluster, I did necessary changes as mentioned in [Apache Flink Official Website](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.8/cluster_execution.html).

I did the following changes:

1. The two points below

   - `ExecutionEnvironment env =    ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();`
   - `ExecutionEnvironment env =    ExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment("taskManagerName",

     portNo,paralelismNo);`
2. Fixing the necessary paths to read input files and write outputs.
3. Generate a thin jar out of the program and put the necessary jar 
           libraries into a folder besides my project jar file called
           `myproj.jar`.
4. copying the data and the jar library and myproj.jar into the cluster
   and run the following command remotely on the cluster:

   ```
    java -cp pathToJarLib \\*  -jar myproj.jar
   ```

But, I get the below error and I don't have any clue to fix the issue. There are no relevant log files which can aid me in fixing this issue.

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/api/common/functions/MapFunction
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2813)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           ... 6 more

Answer (score 3):

Your classpath is obviously not complete. Try to submit via `bin/flink run myproj.jar`. This sets up the classpath correctly.